# How can I do a old-fashioned table of contents with stacked ellipses in CSS?

Tags: css

Here's the table of contents I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/hTt6L/. You'll notice I'm not even trying to do the stacked ellipses, because I don't know what to do.

```
<div style="margin:25px 22px 200px 22px;">
     <div style="text-align:center;font-size:150%;letter-spacing:.1em;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:-.1em;">CONTENTS</div>
     <div style="margin-bottom:9px;">EDITOR&rsquo;S INTRODUCTION</div>
      <div style="margin:0 0 .5em 1em;">1. Historical</div>
      <div style="margin:0 0 .5em 1em;">2. Epistemology</div>
      <div style="margin:0 0 .5em 1em;">3. Epistemology of Morals</div>
      <div style="margin:0 0 .5em 1em;">4. Psychology of Morals</div>
      <div style="margin:0 0 .5em 1em;">5. The Moral System</div>
      <div style="margin:0 0 1.5em 1em;">6. Morals and Theology</div>
     <div style="margin:0 2em .5em 1em;text-indent:-1em;">A REVIEW OF THE PRINCIPAL QUESTIONS IN MORALS</div>
     <div style="margin:0 2em .5em 1em;">INDEX</div>
 </div>
```

Finally, here's what it looks like in context: http://www.dinkypage.com/185740#S2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Fiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/33Kgn/1/). I updated the DOM to have a list instead of just regular DOM. I added `spans` around the text and a new `span` that included the chapter number such as "xi".

Here is the new css:

```
.list li {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:250px;
}
.list li:after {
    content:".................";
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:16px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.list li span {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-right:5px;
}
 .list li .number {
    float:right;
    background-color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you help with one last thing?: [the indenting and dots for "A REVIEW..."](http://jsfiddle.net/33Kgn/2/) won't work. Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to take "A REVIEW OF THE PRINCIPAL QUESTIONS" out by itself and style it to sit above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I [made a new ul for "A REVIEW..." and "INDEX"](http://jsfiddle.net/33Kgn/3/), but that doesn't change the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think Front End Guy's solution is good but I took a different approach, using a background image instead.  Using `content:after` (like Front End Guy did) for your ellipses, just make sure that you include enough to account for wide screens if you don't want a fixed width.  You should also pad those spans, to ensure there is equi-distance from the right of your titles and the left of your page numbers.

I also modified the HTML (there is a reason we both used lists, and you should too). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rkkud/

CSS:

```
li {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAKIAAAAAAP///9fX1ycnJ+3t7QAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAHAP8ALAAAAAAKAAoAAAMNGLrc/jDKRwYUYOqVAAA7);
  background-position: 0 90%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

li:after {    
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
li.first:after {
  content: "ix";
}
li.second:after {
  content: "xii";
  float: right;
}
.index-title {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```